# Sentence Punctuation return True- Spacy

Tags: excel, pandas, spacy

I am writing comma containing sentences to excel using pandas.

```
lists = [sent for sent in doc.sents if ',' in sent.string.lower()]
```

Found out, I can return True or False for it in excel.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",", A1))
```

I use the below code to extract sentences and list it as rows in excel

```
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```

Expected out:

```
Sentence                                 IS_comma_sent
This sentence contains no comma.         False
There is a , in this sentence.           True
```

Any suggestions on how to do it in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
df['Is_comma_sent']=df['Sentence'].str.contains(',')
```